# Using Reader Monad for Dependency Injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, functional-programming, monads

I recently saw the talks [Dead-Simple Dependency Injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio) and [Dependency Injection Without the Gymnastics](http://vimeo.com/44502327) about DI with Monads and was impressed. I tried to apply it on a simple problem, but failed as soon as it got non-trivial. I really would like to see a running version of dependency injection where

- a class that depends on more than one value that has to be injected
- a class that depends on a class that depends on something to be injected

as in the following example

```
trait FlyBehaviour { def fly() }
trait QuackBehaviour { def quack() }
trait Animal { def makeSound() }

// needs two behaviours injected
class Duck(val flyBehaviour: FlyBehaviour, val quackBehaviour: QuackBehaviour) extends Animal 
{
   def quack() = quackBehaviour.quack()
   def fly() = flyBehaviour.fly()
   def makeSound() = quack()
}

// needs an Animal injected (e.g. a Duck)
class Zoo(val animal: Animal)

// Spring for example would be able to provide a Zoo instance
// assuming a Zoo in configured to get a Duck injected and
// a Duck is configured to get impl. of FlyBehaviour and QuackBehaviour injected
val zoo: Zoo = InjectionFramework.get("Zoo")
zoo.animal.makeSound()
```

It would be really helpful to see a sample implementation using the reader Monad since I just feel that I am missing a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "reader monad" is just `Function1`, so all you need to do is accept an argument containing all the things you need. For example:

```
trait Config {
   def fly: FlyBehaviour
   def quack: QuackBehaviour
}

type Env[A] = Config => A
```

Now if you want to construct a `Duck` based on this environment:

```
val a: Env[Animal] = c => new Duck(c.fly, c.quack)
```

And then constructing a `Zoo` based on that is easy:

```
val z: Env[Zoo] = a andThen (new Zoo(_))
```

Using [Scalaz](http://scalaz.org) (or with a bit of work on your own) you can make use of some syntax niceties to "ask" for the config `c`:

```
val z: Env[Zoo] = for {
  c <- ask
} yield new Zoo(Duck(c.fly, c.quack))
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I am curious, are you (or are you aware of any bigger projects) using this in place of spring or goolge guice for DI? Is it preferable according to your experience?

Comment: Yes, we are using this extensively and it is much preferable. If I ever see Spring or Guice again it will be too soon.

Comment: @Apocalisp, could you help me apply this solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341867/how-to-avoid-dependency-injection-in-scala/12363015#12363015?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this last example. `ask` returns a `Reader[Config, Config]`, but then `new Duck...` returns a `Duck`, doesn't it? How does it magically turn into a, I suppose, `Reader[Config, Duck]`? Or maybe it was meant to read `a = new Duck...` ?